# WebApi Per-Request Storage for Self Hosting Mode

Tags: asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

When hosting WebApi is IIS, you have access to HttpContext and can use the items collection to store objects for a single HTTP request.

When self hosting, you no longer have a HttpContext, so what can I use to store an object for a single request ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, there is no direct equivalent of System.Web's HttpContext in self-host.

However, if you wish to start info for the single request, then each HttpRequestMessage exposes a dictionary of <string,object>, called `Properties` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.properties.aspx which you can use to i.e. transport data between handlers, filters, binders and so on.

Comment: Is there a global way of storing objects outside of an individual request. I want to be able to cache the current dbcontext for the lifetime of a request and have it accessable globally

Comment: @kimsagro - You can use a static `ConcurrentDictionary` or `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`

Comment: Is there a way to get information about which message/request is executing when you have no direct access to the `HttpRequestMessage`? For instance using some static property?

Answer (score 0):

For selfhost (no IIS involved) you could construct an attribute class deriving from `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute` type (in the assembly system.web.http .net 4.0+). Then override OnActionExecuted method as below:

```
public class NoResponseCachingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.CacheControl == null)
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.CacheControl = new System.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue();

        actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.CacheControl.NoCache = true;
        actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.CacheControl.NoStore = true;
        actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.CacheControl.MustRevalidate = true;

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

This approach worked for my application.